# Gotta catch em all... Final fantasy style

Tags: final-fantasy-7

Currently I'm cruising through Final Fantasy 7 with no guide; a loose cannon if you will.

What vastly important materia, weapons, or items do I not have the opportunity to go back and get if I miss it the first time?

Comment: It's been a while since I have played this game, and after reading this I really want to start it up...  From what I remember, there are specific materia in different areas that can be accessed at any point during the game. However, as you say, I do believe there are ones that you have to find while on a "mission" or you wont be able to go back... I hope someone can help you out!

Comment: Since you were very specific about "without a guide", are you just looking for a list, and not actual direction on where/how to get the missable items?

Comment: If you're worried about missing items, I'd suggest using a guide. Otherwise, just enjoy the game and don't worry! I also played FFVII fairly recently (maybe 3 years ago now) and, while I perhaps would have liked a few more items during my playthrough, when I reached the end I didn't care about it so much anymore and I just moved on to the next game (which was the original MGS, if I recall!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's just too many things in ff7 to list that are missable (with many that are permanently missable) without a guide.

However, there is a nice [missable items guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/27656) available if you choose to take a look.